# EntLib Caching and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, caching, enterprise-library

I'm trying to get the Microsoft EntLib Caching Block (5.0) working with a SQLite Database and are facing some problems:

When I configured the Caching Block for the MS SQL Database I had to run a sql script which created the db and some stored procedures. But I can not find any information on how to create those procedures and db for the SQLite db.

Is it actually possible to use SQLite with the Caching Block? And if it is, what do I have to do to get it up and running?

Any help is appreciated!
Silvan

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know SQLite doesn't support stored procedures at all.